# How to start an Application at boot up in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, autostart, bootcompleted

I am trying to make an App in Titanium which launches on Startup i.e. as the mobile device startsup. I have seen code written at several places which states to do entry into the andsoid manifest file and some code like

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
  context.startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

But i am not able to figure out that where to put this code. In which file ?? and where ?

Answer (score 0):

This 2 answers will do what you need:

Start BroadcastReceiver after some system broadcast:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877466/988434

Start BroadcastReceiver on boot:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544151/988434

in you BroadcastReceiver you'll implement just call whatever Service/Activty you need.

There an example for that in the question for the 2 answers above.

Tell me if you have any problems unanswered after reading those =].

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to the BOOT_COMPLETED intent filter. The piece of code you just quoted is from a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which will be firing up when the device will boot.

This class has to extend from `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          ...
    }
}
```

Then, you have to register that receiver in your manifest file by doing the following:

```
<receiver 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name="your_package.BootReceiverClassName"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action  android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also you need the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

By the way you have to [make sure that the app is not installed on the SD Card](http://androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/86907.html) otherwise it won't work (but there are possible [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342867/android-how-to-receive-the-boot-signal-with-an-application-installed-on-sdcard)).